# Unable to build - Migrating VC++ code from VS2010 to VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, migration

I am trying to migrate my source from VS2010 to VS2013. It is giving me sleepless nights. I'm getting the below attached compilation error. Please help me out in identifying which compilation switch I'm missing out. I have saved my .sln file from VS2013 to get it adapted to the new environment.

My current compilation settings are as follows:
`PlatformToolset: Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)
Command Line:
/Yu"stdafx.h" /FR"DebugU\" /GS /TP /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"..\Common" /Zi /Gm- /Od /Fd".\DebugU/" /fp:precise /D "_PUGIXML" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" /D "_BIND_TO_CURRENT_VCLIBS_VERSION" /D "_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0700" /D "_USING_V110_SDK71_" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /showIncludes /MTd /Fa".\DebugU/" /EHsc /nologo /Fo".\DebugU/" /Fp".\DebugU/xxxxxxxx.pch"`

Compilation Log with "ShowIncludes"
`1>  pugixml.cpp
1>  Note: including file: d:\vistasonicpoc\common\pugixml.hpp
1>  Note: including file: d:\vistasonicpoc\common\pugiconfig.hpp
1>  Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\exception
1>  Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstddef
1>  Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\cstddef
1>  Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\yvals.h
1>  Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xkeycheck.h
1>  Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>  Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\use_ansi.h
1>  Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\initializer_list
1>  Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtr1common
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtr1common(421): error C2159: more than one storage class specified
1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtr1common(421) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Has_result_type<_Ty>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtr1common(421): error C3557: a function cannot have both a return type and a late-specified return type
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xtr1common(421): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstddef(203): error C3557: a function cannot have both a return type and a late-specified return type
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstddef(203): warning C4042: 'std::plus<void>::operator ()' : has bad storage class
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstddef(203): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstddef(218): error C3557: a function cannot have both a return type and a late-specified return type
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstddef(218): warning C4042: 'std::minus<void>::operator ()' : has bad storage class
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstddef(218): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstddef(233): error C3557: a function cannot have both a return type and a late-specified return type
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstddef(233): warning C4042: 'std::multiplies<void>::operator ()' : has bad storage class
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstddef(233): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstddef(248): error C3557: a function cannot have both a return type and a late-specified return type
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstddef(248): warning C4042: 'std::equal_to<void>::operator ()' : has bad storage class
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstddef(248): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstddef(263): error C3557: a function cannot have both a return type and a late-specified return type
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstddef(263): warning C4042: 'std::less<void>::operator ()' : has bad storage class
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xstddef(263): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`

Comment: If you use the standard ``v120`` toolset rather than ``v120_xp``, does it compile?

Comment: I tried with both toolset, its the same error log.

Comment: I'd suggest compiling the file with ``/P`` and looking at the preprocessed output just before the point of failure.

Comment: Seems like you're using the vs120 includes but the vs100 compiler. The xtr1common header is quite different in both versions. The vs120 uses newer features which the old compiler didn't have. Check the correct path under project properties -> VC++ Directories -> Executable Directories.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found out that the flag `/Zc:auto` was set to `/Zc:auto-` and this was causing all the errors.

You don't seem to have it specified in the command line but it could help someone else having the same type of error.

[Zc:auto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293615.aspx)